# Select with Case - amalgamating results into single record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query as follows

```
SELECT        
FGB.TEMPLATE_DETAILS_REF, FGB.TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_REF, FGB.DFEE_ELEMENT, 
    CASE 
    WHEN Condition = 'A' THEN SUM(FGS.Weighted) END AS CondA, 
    CASE 
    WHEN Condition = 'B' THEN SUM(FGS.Weighted) END AS CondB, 
    CASE 
    WHEN Condition = 'C' THEN SUM(FGS.Weighted) END AS CondC, 
    CASE 
    WHEN Condition = 'D' THEN SUM(FGS.Weighted) END AS CondD
    FROM            FGBlockSummary AS FGB INNER JOIN
                             FGSurveyItem AS FGS ON FGB.TEMPLATE_DETAILS_REF = FGS.TEMPLATE_DETAILS_REF AND FGB.TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_REF = FGS.TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_REF AND 
                             FGB.DFEE_ELEMENT = FGS.DFEE_ELEMENT
    GROUP BY FGB.TEMPLATE_DETAILS_REF, FGB.TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_REF, FGB.DFEE_ELEMENT, FGS.Condition
```

which produces results as follows:

1. 16  109 Ceilings    NULL    14101.47    NULL    NULL
2. 16  109 Ceilings    NULL    NULL        227.68  NULL

How can I amalgamate the results into a single row eg

1. 16   109 Ceilings    NULL    14101.47    227.68  NULL

Thanks

Comment: You didn't give us a very good example, what happens when there are two of the same field but different values, how will it decide? At the moment all you've shown us is that if they are are the same leave it or choose whichever isn't null.

Comment: There will be a maximum of 4 records for each entity, determined by the 'Condition' being either 'A', 'B', 'C' or 'D'. What I want to do is amalgamate the values associated with each of these 'Condition' values into a single result record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

I moved the `SUM` outside of the `CASE`s and eliminated `FGS.Condition` from the `GROUP BY`. It'll have the side-effect of changing your `NULL` values to '0', but that might be tolerable?

```
SELECT
  FGB.TEMPLATE_DETAILS_REF
 ,FGB.TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_REF
 ,FGB.DFEE_ELEMENT
 ,CondA = SUM( 
          CASE
            WHEN FGS.Condition = 'A' THEN FGS.Weighted
            ELSE 0
          END)
 ,CondB = SUM( 
          CASE
            WHEN FGS.Condition = 'B' THEN FGS.Weighted
            ELSE 0
          END)
 ,CondC = SUM( 
          CASE
            WHEN FGS.Condition = 'C' THEN FGS.Weighted
            ELSE 0
          END)
 ,CondD = SUM( 
          CASE
            WHEN FGS.Condition = 'D' THEN FGS.Weighted
            ELSE 0
          END)
FROM
  FGBlockSummary AS FGB
INNER JOIN
  FGSurveyItem   AS FGS
    ON
    FGB.TEMPLATE_DETAILS_REF = FGS.TEMPLATE_DETAILS_REF
      AND FGB.TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_REF = FGS.TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_REF
      AND FGB.DFEE_ELEMENT = FGS.DFEE_ELEMENT
GROUP BY
  FGB.TEMPLATE_DETAILS_REF
 ,FGB.TEMPLATE_STRUCTURE_REF
 ,FGB.DFEE_ELEMENT;
```

Comment: Perfect thanks and zeroes instead of Nulls is helpful too. Top man!